# What is the highest possible big O complexity?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Curious O(n^n) is pretty high but O(n^n^n) is higher and O(n^n^n^n) is higher still. Is there a highest big O?

Comment: There's no such thing. Call the highest 'foo' so O(foo). Then (2^foo grows faste O(2^foo). So there can be no highest

Comment: But for your amusement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation

Comment: @displayName, which size of infinity? (some are provably bigger than others)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: The bigger one...

Comment: @displayName O(n) is bigger than O(∞) because ∞ is constant yes?

Comment: @SamRobison: Yes, but this constant is too huge in the face of any f(n) to ignore. In Big-O we ignore the constants because when n → ∞, those constants become irrelevant. This _constant_ that we are talking about can't be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exists a maximal big O complexity given by `f`, that is,

```
g(n) ∈ O(f(n)), ∀ g:ℝ->ℝ
```

Then, let `g(n) = f(n)^2`.

Since `lim f(n) = ∞`,

```
    f(n)    f(n)     1
lim ──── = ────── = ──── = 0
    g(n)   f(n)^2   f(n)
```

That means `g(n) ∉ O(f(n))`. Contradiction.